# Find the largest rectangle dimension

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a matrix of ‘O’ and ‘X’, find the largest rectangle whose sides consist of ‘X’

#### Example 1

```
XXXXX
X0X0X
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

Output : largest rectangle size is 4 x 5

#### Example 2

```
0X0XX
X0X0X
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

Output: largest rectangle size is 2 x 5 (last two rows of the matrix)

I am able to make o(*n*<sup>4</sup>) algorithm in which I look for each combination. Can anybody please give some hints or idea for better optimized algorithm.

My Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int arr[1001][1001];
int check(int left[][1001],int up[][1001], int m, int n, int leftx, int lefty, int rightx, int righty)
{
    if(((righty - lefty) == (left[rightx][righty] - left[rightx][lefty])) and ((left[leftx][righty] - left[leftx][lefty]) ==( righty - lefty)))
    {
        if(((rightx - leftx) == ( up[rightx][righty] - up[leftx][righty] )) and ((up[rightx][lefty] - up[leftx][lefty]) == rightx - leftx))
        {
            return (2*(left[leftx][righty] - left[leftx][lefty]   +   up[rightx][lefty]  - up[leftx][lefty] ));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void solve(int arr[][1001], int m, int n)
{
    int left[1001][1001];
    int up[1001][1001];
    for(int i=0 ; i<m ;i++)
    {
        int prev = 1;
        for(int j=0 ; j<n ;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j] == 1)
            {
                left[i][j] = prev;
                ++prev;
            }
            else if(arr[i][j] == -1)
            {
                left[i][j] = -1;
                prev =1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ;i++)
    {
        int prev = 1;
        for(int j=0 ; j<m ;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j][i] == 1)
            {
                up[j][i] = prev;
                ++prev;
            }
            else if(arr[j][i] == -1)
            {
                up[j][i] = -1;
                prev =1;
            }
        }
    }


    int max = 0;
    int max_col = 0;
    int max_row = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < m-1 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j<n-1; j++)
        {

            for(int k = m-1 ; k >i ; k--)
            {
                for(int l = n-1; l >j ; l--)
                {
                    if(((k-i > max_row) || (l-j > max_col)))
                    {   
                        int maxi = check(left,up,m,n,i,j,k,l);
                        if(maxi > max)
                        {
                            max = maxi;
                            max_col = l-j;
                            max_row = k-i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Dimension = "<<max_col<<"\t"<<max_row<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @SimonKraemer codereview requires a working code.

Comment: @MohitJain As OP stated: *"I am able to make o(n^4) algorithm in which i look for each combination"*

Comment: @SimonKraemer Need a working code.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I didn;t put my code here because I don't want a code for above problem. I have stated that in that algorithm I looked in each combination which is O(n*m)^2 ~ O(n^4) . I simply want a hint to think in different direction.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Have you read the on-topic pages for both sites you just recommended? If not, please don't make any other recommendations till you do. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It's a terrible question for both sites.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Its boundary is made up of 'x' and largest matrix is of size `4x5`

Comment: @EmptyData he's saying that if the boundary is X then it's not part of the rectangle, otherwise it's not "surrounded" but part of it.

Comment: @Pimgd I didn't get you. In example largest matrix which is having all of its boundary made up of 'x' and it is having size `4x5`

Comment: @EmptyData When you say "sub-rectangle surrounded by x", then you mean to say that "there must be X around it". For there to be X around something, the X that is around the thing is not part of the thing. There is no box around the box, there is a box around the contents. Recommend you rephrase your question to "the largest rectangle with the edges consisting of X" - e.g. "find me the biggest box", not "the biggest contents which are in a box".

Comment: @Pimgd Changed the description now.

Comment: How about going over each item and checking what is the largest rectangle that has the item in its corner? Should be bounded by O(n^2).

Comment: @Mast: From [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *"If you have a question about...algorithm and data structure concepts"*. From [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *"If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…Performance"*.  Yes, `programmers.stackexchange.com` would have required OP to post the code he can produce, yet I don't see any reason why the question should be off-topic on any if both sites (at least when rephrased accordingly).

Comment: @o_weisman It's not about the corners, but the whole sites must consist of `X`

Comment: @SimonKraemer I get the idea you're pushing for, but it looks like OP has an algorithm in mind, but doesn't feel like implementing it just yet because he thinks there's a better on. Code Review would require him to implement his solution, and then we would improve his solution, but might not recommend the better algorithm just because it doesn't come up in review.

Comment: Just look at the Related Questions. There's plenty of precedent for this kind of question on Stack Overflow. I suggest that we drop the discussion about the choice of forum.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I understood the question. If the algorithm starts at a specific x item and assumes that it is the corner of a rectangle, it should be relatively simple to construct an algorithm that starts traversing horizontally and vertically from that item to find the largest rectangle it can. The algorithm for each item would not exceed O(n) as far as I can tell.

Comment: @o_weisman OP's `O(n^4)` doesn't seem right - It should be more like `O(n^2)` or `O(n * log n)`

Comment: @SimonKraemer Added my code in question.

Comment: @EmptyData Your misconception is that you think that iterating over a matrix with size `x*y` would require `O(n²)`. Yet your matrix is just `x*y` datapoints. So even if you have a nested for loop to do so it's still `O(n)`. Think about it this way: You could easily change you matrix to an array and iterate over it in one single for loop.